# Is there a way to "archive" projects in git repository?

Tags: git

Now, my working directory continues to grow and I know that some of the projects won't be touched for a while (or probably ever, being obsolete). However, I'd like to keep them in case they are resurrected at some point. What would be a proper way to hide them? That is, they wouldn't show up in the main folder and would be ignored by git searches. At the same time, I'd like to be able to reopen them if needed without much trouble as well. I can't simply delete the folder because there are files present in .gitignore and they will not be recoverable.

Some probably unrelated appendix: I'm using it on my own, there are no others contributing, I don't share it with anyone, this is just my own personal internal work which no one else uses or sees. Just keeping a backup and history of my projects. Some "projects" are merely small apps which could be a 2-week work.

I'm on Linux if it matters.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're keeping every project in a single git repo? It's much cleaner and easier to manage if you keep them as individual repositories. Commits and all repo activity is then contained to the project and you can "archive" projects like you describe.

For example, I work on private one-person projects, open source projects with lots of contributors, and large corporate projects. Either way:

- All projects have their own repo.
- I can treat them all differently if I need. Granting access, archiving old projects, etc.
- Reviewing history, rebasing, searching logs for breaking changes, etc are all contained to the project I'm actively working on.

Comment: One git repo is handy because I just do regular commits from one same place and sure I am not forgetting it. I also have the ability to search through all the projects' histories (many of them related). Many repositories seems like another sort of clatter...

Comment: Personally, having everything in one repo seems extremely cluttered so I suppose we have different perspectives. What happens when you need to grant access for a single project, or add deploy/build tasks, etc. I wouldn't want users of my open source work to see completely unrelated projects piled in there

Comment: Please see the edit - it is for my personal use, no one else sees it. I probably was not very clear about it, but that's why I'm saying I don't want to go into too much trouble about it...

Comment: Still, unless the files you're tracking are all related it's just inefficient to have them all tracked in a single repo. Imagine keeping all of the files on your computer in a single folder, eventually you're stuck with a big pile of unrelated files with little organization that winds up being difficult to sort/separate.

Comment: I don't see how it is related. All files on my computer are organized into folders and I can access them from one entry point. Why is it inefficient? Projects are still in different folders, why having them in different repositories is better? I need to remember to commit every time I'm in the appropriate folder, I can't git search across all the projects... And yes, they are related in some way..

Comment: It's honestly less of an issue when it's just you - but now you're forever stuck with the history for every single project tied in with the history of them all. Now you're asking how to "archive" portions of it, but you can't - every project is entwined with everything else in the repo. You can remove the files but the history is all there.

Comment: Well, if this is impossible just add it to your answer :)

Comment: @sashkello imagine you create a branch - it affects multiple projects, however you only work on one single project within that branch. Usually, even if you have projects related to each other you end up with multiple git repositories and/or modules. It is a common practice: i.e. you create the following repositories `<project>-backend`, `<project>-frontend`, `<project>-android`, `<project>-ios` for different related projects.

Comment: What about simply having an "Archive" folder where I can copy the obsolete projects which is then added to .gitignore?

Comment: Then you completely lose the connection between the file and its history for those files. If you actually lose your entire archive folder without backups, you have to then start digging into the repo history to get all of those files back.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `git clone --bare` of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to my mind is that you could create a separate branch for every project folder you have inside your repo (`git clone` then remove unnecessary folders) and "promote" them all to act as the new master branches. The tricky part would be that you would have to take extra care every time you decide to merge those back into the main master branch.

```
master (all projects) ---- "master 1" (project 1)
 \   \
  \   \_____"master 2" (project 2)
   \
    \_______ "master 3" (project 3)
```

And I have to agree what others said about dealing with multiple projects inside a single repository - it will always come back to bite you no matter what reasoning was behind doing so.